# Automation of Web-based interface to database

Tags: html, database, firefox, firebug

I need to automate data insert with web based user interface (i dont'have access directly to DB, only through web interface).
Using firebug (or another tool) how i can log click on HTML objects in page?

Comment: Hi. Can you post some code for us to look at peas.

Comment: What did you try so far? Side note: [Firebug is discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).